# Problem with 'try.....except' throws an Syntax error for ROOT files

Tags: python

I am trying to find corrupted root files in a dir. Basically, my code throws and SyntaxError: invalid syntax when trying the following

```
import ROOT as root
import sys
import glob


dir=sys.argv[1]
txtfiles = []
for file in glob.glob(dir+"/*.root"):
    f = root.TFile(file,'r')
    try :
        myTree = f.Get("AC1B")

        except IOError:
            print 'this is not good',f
            continue
        else :
            print 'the filename is ',file, myTree.GetEntries()
```

I ve tried also just except: but this also does not work.

Answer (score 5):

Your `except` statement must be on the same indentation level as the `try`. It's currently nested inside the `try`:

```
import ROOT as root
import sys
import glob


dir = sys.argv[1]
txtfiles = []
for file in glob.glob(dir + "/*.root"):
    f = root.TFile(file,'r')
    try:
        myTree = f.Get("AC1B")

    except IOError:
        print 'this is not good',f
        continue
    else:
        print 'the filename is ',file, myTree.GetEntries()
```

Comment: Oh, right thanks! However, still the code exits on the first corrupted file..
<br/>
<br/>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "check.py", line 17, in <module>
     print 'the filename is ',file, myTree.GetEntries() AttributeError: 'TObject' object has no attribute 'GetEntries'

Comment: @Terma This indicates that your `f.Get` is not triggering an error, but returning a different object than you're expecting. This thread indicates that you should be using `f.GetObject` instead of `f.Get`: https://root-forum.cern.ch/t/tfile-get-path-to-ttree-returns-a-class-root-tobject-instead-of-class-root-ttree/30406/2